# create attribute xml using python

Tags: python, xml, attributes, tags

How to edit tag in xml and give attribute using python?

step 1 :
change name tag (spaces removed) -->
tag `<Document_Type>` to be `<Document>`

step 2 :
give attribute to tag --> `<Document>` to be `<Document Type ="SPTInduk">`

below is an example .xml and its expectations

before:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<batch>
  <Document_Type>
    <Ekspor>0.0</Ekspor>
    <PPNDipungutSendiriDPP>269789662720400.0</PPNDipungutSendiriDPP>
  </Document_Type>
</batch>
```

expected results:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<batch>
  <Document Type="SPTInduk">
    <Ekspor>0.0</Ekspor>
    <PPNDipungutSendiriDPP>269789662720400.0</PPNDipungutSendiriDPP>
  </Document>
</batch>
```

Comment: What did you try so far and what is the problem?

Comment: change it as string, then replace old text with new text, then save as xml

Comment: Share the code please so we can have a look

Answer (score 0):

```
stringroot = stringroot.replace('<Document>','<Document Type="SPTInduk">')
stringroot = ET.fromstring(stringroot)
stringroot = ET.ElementTree(stringroot)
stringroot.write(r"{}\{}.xml".format(eksport_folder,file_name), encoding="utf-8")
```